# BeautifulSoup: scraping titles from www.themoviedb.org

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know this is specific, but I'm looking to find a way to scrape the following website:

https://www.themoviedb.org/discover/movie?page=1

and return a list of the titles of the movies.

I've tried BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/discover/movie?page=1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
soup
```

However I can't find any of the titles in the output. I'm new to this, but I was wondering if anyone could provide an example of how you would do this?

Comment: I suggest using the built in API for tmdb. See here: https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML, it seems info about movies is located inside `<div>`s with the class `info`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.themoviedb.org/discover/movie?page=1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
items = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'info'})

for item in items:
    print(item.p.a['title'])
```

Output:

```
Split
Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children
Deadpool
Captain America: Civil War
X-Men: Apocalypse
Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them
Arrival
Tomorrow Everything Starts
Doctor Strange
La La Land
Sing
The Great Wall
Rogue One: A Star Wars Story
Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice
Hacksaw Ridge
Zootopia
Inferno
Star Trek Beyond
Now You See Me 2
Passengers
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close:

```
for x in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'item poster card'}): 
    print list(x.find_all('a')[1])
```